# Check if JavaScript dialog box is open in a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, dialog, acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm trying to make a pair of dialog boxes that show upon opening a PDF; one dialog will show if the PDF is opened in a reader that supports Adobe Reader's level of JavaScript functionality, and the other will show if the previous dialog is not shown (ie, if the PDF is opened in a reader with little JavaScript support, which means the first dialog cannot be shown).

The problem I'm running into right now is trying to get the second dialog to show. I tried using a try-catch, but I'm assuming it didn't work because the first dialog box didn't actually fail to show... or something.

So how would I go about showing the second dialog if the first is not shown due to a lack of support?

Here's my current code (which is written as a "page open" action in the page properties):

```
try {
     var d = dialog();

     d.execDialog();
} catch (e) {
     app.alert("ERROR: Incompatible reader; please install Adobe Reader to open this file.");
}

function dialog()
{
     var dialogDescriptor =
    {
        // Dialog description goes here
    };

     var dialogObject =
    {
        execDialog: function() { return app.execDialog(dialogDescriptor); },
    };

 return dialogObject;

}
```

The reason I'm using app.execDialog is because there will be hyperlinks in the first dialog box.

Also, I'm completely new to using JavaScript and working with PDFs, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Acrobat and Reader will frequently crash if you try to show two dialogs at the same time. You should first determine which of the two dialogs is appropriate to display and then display that one.

Comment: I'm not trying to show two dialog boxes at once, though. I'm trying to have one display if the other fails to do so due to a lack of javascript support; ie, I want the app.alert box to appear if the execDialog function fails due to a lack of functionality, such as in non-adobe readers like Foxit.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the PDF viewer supports the Dialog object by testing if app.execDialog is a function. Something like this...

```
if (typeof app.execDialog === "function") {
    // Can show Acrobat dialogs    
}
else {
    // Can't show Acrobat Dialogs
}
```

That kind of code works for any function or object method.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried using this in the code, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried reversing it (ie, if typeof !== "function"), and the non-adobe readers seemed to use the else code just like adobe, so it seems that non-adobe readers still recognize execDialog as a function.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried the code with Foxit and the desktop version does indeed claim to support execDialog... and it does... it's just completely wrong. If you need to verify that you are in an Adobe viewer rather than just determine if execDialog is supported, enumerate the plugins (app.plugins) and check if any of them start with "ADBE" - I've found that method to be the most reliable.